# Potential Energy in a System and its Relation to the Total Energy

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics, energy-conservation, potential-energy

In [this answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/210239/62221) it was stated that potential energy is a property of a system and not an individual particle.

If we have two particles (1 and 2) interacting via a conservative force, we can write an equation regarding the total energy of the system and its conservation:

KE1 + KE2 + PE(sys) = KE1' + KE2' + PE(sys)'

Where the **'** indicates *final*.

I know this equation is incorrect, but my question is *why is it incorrect*?

I most definitely am interpreting [this answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/210239/62221) incorrectly.

Comment: When one part of the system is effectively invariant---as in the case where human sized things are moving around near the surface of the Earth---it is expedient to ascribe the potential energy to the small thing. It's just that if someone took the planet away it would affect the behavior of the experiment. On the other hand, if you are talking about the elastic energy of a spring of natural length $l_0$ with a mobile mass on each end, then the potential should be written $U(\vec{x}_1,\vec{x}_2) = \frac{1}{2}k(|\vec{x}_1-\vec{x_2}|-l_0)^2$ and is obviously a function of both positions.

Comment: Your equation is correct. Why do you think that its incorrect?

Comment: @garyp So when finding the total energy of the system it would be correct to count the potential energy once (instead of twice for both particles)?

Comment: Potential energy is the energy associated with the interaction between pairs of objects, and the positions of those objects.  So you calculate it once for every pair of objects.  Two objects: once.  Three objects: three times (and add them together). Four particles: six times (and add them together). *One* particle: *not defined!* If you throw a ball, there are two objects interacting by gravity: the ball and the earth.

Comment: @garyp You can derive KE1+PE(sys)=KE1'+PE(sys)' from the work-energy theorem and the definition of potential energy. Doesn't this contradict KE1 + KE2 + PE(sys) = KE1' + KE2' + PE(sys)'? I'm still a bit unclear on this. Could you provide any references on this subject? Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by PE(sys)?  What is the system?  That's always the first question to settle.  What is the system?  The answer to that determines how to proceed with energy accounting.

Comment: @garyp Two particles interacting with each other via a force field

Comment: So you are missing KE2 from the equation on the top line, aren't you?

Comment: @garyp yes. I feel as if I'm deriving it incorrectly

Comment: BTW if your system is both particles, then the Work-Energy theorem becomes $0=\Delta E$.  There is no work being done on the system.  Perhaps that's what causing you difficulty.

Comment: @garyp I understand that the total energy doesn't change. I'm just concerned with how the energy is converted within the system. According to the work-energy theorem and the potential energy definition (for particle one), the total potential energy of the system is converted to the kinetic energy of one particle, which leaves no energy for the other particle to move. The same can be said for the second particle. Maybe I'm missing something, but this confuses me greatly.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30119/discussion-between-garyp-and-andrew-yates).

Answer (score 1):

To offer insight on the comment about potential energy being defined for a system, rather than just the body itself.

This stems from the definition of potential energy. For a *body* in a gravitational field, the *source* of the field had to do work in order to bring this *body* to its current position. Generally, potential energy is defined to be zero at an infinite distance away from the *source* of the field. Without identifying the *source*, there is no sense of where this reference point is. You can't measure a quantity that relies on a reference point without a reference point! Hence, there is no concept of what the potential energy of the *body* is. Potential energy is defined for a **system**. Without both a *source* and the *body*, there is no true sense of potential energy.